# if $w$ is a complex number, how to show that $w^\left(1/2\right)$ has 2 roots? except the case for $w=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am looking for a convincing argument to show that if $w$ is a complex number, $w^{\frac 12}$ has 2 different roots.

Comment: The adjectives "positive" and "negative" carry little meaning when talking about complex numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by a "positive" complex number?

Comment: my apologies. what i meant was some similarity with the root of real numbers

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $0$ has only one square root

Comment: $w=0$ is an exception. You don't have two different roots in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that if $(x+iy)^2=w$, then $((-x)+i(-y))^2=w$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the polar representation $w=r e^{i(\phi+2k\pi)}$.

Its square root yields 2 distinct roots that repeat ad infinitum.

That is:
$$w^{1/2}=\sqrt r e^{i(\phi/2+k\pi)}$$
If $r=0$ we have only 1 root, which is 0. Otherwise we get the 2 distinct roots $\sqrt r e^{i\phi/2}$ and $\sqrt r e^{i(\phi/2+\pi)}$. All other values of $k$ map to these 2 roots due to the $2\pi$ periodicity.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. we are talking about 2 distinct (non-trivial) answers

Comment: @math_student, I have extended my answer to clarify how we do get 2 distinct roots.